# Arcpy: Calculate new field from user input and existing data

Tags: python, arcpy

Can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this create fields from a calculation. The code creates the new field in the shapefile as selected by the user but I keep getting a 9999 error on every attempt I have to go further. I am rather new to Python and ArcPy, if anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated. The code is to work as a tool from an exported route from a network analysis and provide a fuel cost which changes slightly in relation to the speed limit of the road. Thanks.

```
        import arcpy
        from arcpy import env
        import os

        inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)      # Input feature class
        distanceField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)      # Name of distance field in                           input fc
        speedField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)      # Name of speed field in input feature class
        price = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))      # Input the current price of gas in $/Liter
        mpg = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4))      # Input vehicle mpg in MPG

        arcpy.AddField_management(inputFC, 'Cost', 'DOUBLE') #create cost field
        rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inputFC)
        #row = rows.NextRow()
        #arcpy.AddMessage(row.GetValue(distanceField))
        for row in rows:
            arcpy.AddMessage(row.length_12)
            distance = row.getValue(distanceField)
            arcpy.AddMessage(distance)
            lperkm = row.getValue(mpg)
            milageupdate = lperkm * 2.35214  #convert mpg to liters per kilometer
            if speedField <= 30:
                cost =(price * 0.07 * distance)/ milageupdate -(milageupdate * (0.07))
            elif speedField >30 and speedField <50:
                cost =(price  * distance)/ milageupdate -(milageupdate * (0.03))
            elif speedField >50 and speedField <90:
                cost =(price  * distance)/ milageupdate
            row.setValue('Cost', cost)
            rows.updateRow(row)
        del row, rows
```

Answer (score 5):

As a starting point, your search cursor should be an update cursor if you are attempting to update the values of anything. Here's some information on the various cursors available to you in ArcPy: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000

```
 rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inputFC)
```

Comment: AHight, PolyGeo
Thanks a lot for the quick answers, really appreciate the help.

Comment: If by chance you have have 10.1 you should try the new cursors in the data access module. They are significantly faster. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell the variable speedField is set to a field name (i.e. text string) and then tested to see whether it is less than a number (30).

Try changing

```
if speedField <= 30: 
  cost =(price * 0.07 * distance)/ milageupdate -(milageupdate * (0.07)) 
elif speedField >30 and speedField <50: 
  cost =(price  * distance)/ milageupdate -(milageupdate * (0.03)) 
elif speedField >50 and speedField <90: 
  cost =(price  * distance)/ milageupdate
```

to

```
if row.getValue(speedField) <= 30: 
  cost =(price * 0.07 * distance)/ milageupdate -(milageupdate * (0.07)) 
elif 30 < row.getValue(speedField) <50: 
  cost =(price  * distance)/ milageupdate -(milageupdate * (0.03)) 
elif 50 < row.getValue(speedField) <90: 
  cost =(price  * distance)/ milageupdate
```

and, as @AHigh says, you will need an UpdateCursor rather than a SearchCursor

You should also double check whether the upper ranges should all be "less than" or "less than or equal to".  You use the latter for 30 but the former for 50 and 90.

Answer (score 3):

A trick to success that I have found is use the shell to test bits and pieces of your code and then integrate it back into the total package this way you can check the output. Incremental development is a good way to isolate errors quickly rather than having to sort through the whole code. Another useful free Python reference is How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/

Comment: +1 That's a good strategy and good advice, thanks.  Welcome to our site!

Answer (score 1):

Are `arcpy.AddMessage(row.length_12)` and `arcpy.AddMessage(distance)` coming through fine? If not, try casting the parameters to strings, e.g. `arcpy.AddMessage(str(row.length_12))`.

In `lperkm = row.getValue(mpg)` you're passing a `float` data type to `row.getValue(field_name)` which is expecting a `str`. Maybe you meant `lperkm = row.getValue('mpg')`. PolyGeo and AHigh are right as well, so fix those issues too.

`9999` generally means that a function inside `arcpy` has failed (otherwise you'll get a `TypeError`, `IOError` or something else along those lines). Not very useful, I know, but at least you know you have to look for the error in the function parameters (and by the way, make sure you're using the right functions while you're at it as well).

If you're new to python but haven't done so already, check out the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) in the python docs.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. After changing the UpdateCurser The row length messages are coming through alright, that is the last thing I get. I have determined that the error is on the line:
       lperkm = row.getValue(mpg)

I've converted the float to a string with the same function parameter error in the result
       mpgx = str(mpg)
       lperkm = row.getValue(mpgx)

I'll check out tutorials as recommended.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line? Do you have a field named `mpg` in your table whose value for this row you're trying to find out? If so, you want to replace `lperkm = row.getValue(mpg)` with `lperkm = row.getValue('mpg')` (verbatim).

Comment: There is no mpg row in the table, the mpg is a user input that is to be used as a parameter. After the mpg is converted to liters per km it is used as one of the inputs to calculate the "cost" field.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do now. There are many strange things going on in your script, though, and I suggest taking the time to think through it again.

Remove the row `lperkm = row.getValue(mpg)` entirely, then change the next row to `lperkm = mpg * 2.35214`. Then rewrite the math bit using `lperkm` (PolyGeo gave you the right if conditions, but the formula is wrong). Work it out on paper if you have to.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, script is working. Learned a lot and I'm quite thrilled. As you suggested it was a couple pieces of messy syntax and a lot of bad math. Will be more careful in the future.